# Making SDWebImage appear with fade in animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, sdwebimage

I would like to set an animation, when an image is loaded.

I use `SDWebImage` to load pictures:

```
if let photoUrlString = post?.photoUrl {
         let photoUrl = URL(string: photoUrlString)
         picImg.sd_setImage(with: photoUrl)
}
```

How can I code a "fade in" effect when the picture is loaded?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit: SDWebImage provides seven transitions that execute only when the image is first downloaded ([source](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/SDWebImageTransition.m)). These transitions use CATransition.

```
guard let photoUrlString = post?.photoUrl else {
    return
}

let photoUrl = URL(string: photoUrlString)

picImg.sd_imageTransition = .fade
picImg.sd_setImage(with: photoUrl)
```

Comment: Beware if you are using a UITableViewCell though. one huge benefit of SDWebImage is image cacheing, and when scrolling a large UITableView, the images are allocated and deallocated. Using CATransition could cause the pictures to fade from one to another if you have multiple. You'll have a bit more work if this is the case.

Comment: Indeed, that's exactly the problem. Image fade to another... :/ Moreover, with the pagination system, when new pictures are added, all the pictures are fading ...

Comment: @KevinB I updated the answer. SDWebImage actually provides their 
own implementation of transitions.

Comment: I don't know why, it's woking sometimes and sometimes not. But that's better that what I had ! Thank you very much :)